# big Little A15/A7 would anyone use Thumb2

Tags: arm

I may be comparing apples to oranges but in new Socs where there are A7 and A15 together, would anyone care to run on Thumb.

Is there any use case to run thumb at all in those Soc's

Comment: thumb (without the thumb-2 extensions) is the only or most portable instruction set in the arm family.  Almost all devices, certainly all current devices support thumb (not counting the 64 bit arch in this statement). arm and thumb2 cannot make that statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinguish between Thumb and Thumb-2. Thumb was just a 16-bit compressed version of the ARM-Instruction set with a lot of limitations. Thumb-2 is a mixed 16/32-bit instruction set, which uses some before undefined thumb-instructions. It added many extensions and brought the instruction-set on-par with the normal ARM instruction set. These days Thumb-2 is preferred in most situations, as the denser instructions allow for a better icache utilization and require less memory bandwidth. In some cases (like tight loops) pure ARM-Code still can perform considerably better, but most of the time the difference is negligable. It mainly depends on your code being able to use the extra registers which can be more easily used in pure ARM-Code.